# how to access values from the url using python

Tags: python, url, anchor, web.py

I am working with python web.py framework,i had an anchor tag with html code as below for example

```
<p><a href = "/edit.py?tr=%d"%1>Edit</a></p>
```

So when i click this link it goes to `edit.py` file in my project directory, but as you observe i am passing some values after edit.py like `/edit.py?tr=%d"%1`. Actually i will pass these values dynamically in further process.

Here after redirecting to `edit.py`, how to access the values after `?`  from the py file?
because my intention is to edit the record after saving in to database.

Answer (score 1):

You can get them using web.input, e.g.

```
def GET(self):
    data = web.input()
    tr = data.tr
```

Documentation is avaliable here: http://webpy.org/cookbook/input

Comment: thanks for replying actually this is the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120085/how-to-call-a-class-url-from-html-tags-using-python-web-py-framework